# codeigniter Undefined variable: finmasuk and if it disapear, datatable wont show

Tags: php, codeigniter

i know this is common question, bet i've tried everything on here and my problem not solved yet. im new at codeigniter and maybe PHP.

like what i've mention above. i have a problem with my code. error show when i try to get data from my database table and show them on html table.

1st error is, when i try to use "foreach" error says "Undefined variable: finmasuk".

2nd error is, when "Undefined variable: finmasuk" disapear, there's some error on my table.

this is my code..

**controller**

```
     public function finmasuk(){
     $this->load->model('m_input');
     $data["finmasuk"] = $this->m_input->finmasuk();
     $this->load->view("input/standar", $data);
     }
```

**model**

```
    public function finmasuk(){
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("pemasukan");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query; 
    }
```

**view**

```
    <?php if($finmasuk->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($finmasuk->result() as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->nomor;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->tanggal_input;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->jenis_pemasukan;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->nominal;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->keterangan;?></td>
      </tr>

       <?php }}
         else
          { ?>
             <tr>
               <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
             </tr>
          <?php  }?>
```

error says that "Undefined variable: finmasuk" but i think i have

> $data["finmasuk"]

Comment: can you post how you access the variable?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**model**

```
public function finmasuk(){
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("pemasukan");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result(); 
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php if(!empty($finmasuk)){
    foreach($finmasuk as $row) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->nomor;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->tanggal_input;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->jenis_pemasukan;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->nominal;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->keterangan;?></td>
      </tr>

       <?php }}
         else
          { ?>
             <tr>
               <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
             </tr>
          <?php  }?>
```

Comment: "Undefined variable: finmasuk"  is disapear but it says no data found. i have data on my database, and it should be show in my table.

Comment: use print_r on the model `print_r($query->result());` before you return the data, does it print any data

Comment: then it means you should recheck your query and data stored in that table

Comment: i did. if the systac error, it shoul show any error. BTW, thanks for your help. im gonna find another source to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a few debugging tricks to check if your query is returning any rows at all.

Controller

```
 public function finmasuk(){
     $this->load->model('m_input');
     $rowsReturned = $this->m_input->finmasuk()->num_rows();
     echo $rowsReturned;
     }
```

Model

```
public function finmasuk(){
    return $this->db->get('pemasukan');
}
```

Another Option - This checks for query results as an array

Controller

```
 public function finmasuk(){
     $this->load->model('m_input');
     $resultArray = $this->m_input->finmasuk()->result_array();
     var_dump($resultArray); 
     echo "<br>";
     echo "Count - ".count($resultArray); //Get number of rows in 
     }
```

Model

```
public function finmasuk(){
    return $this->db->get('pemasukan');
    }
```

Comment: error. 
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Comment: error. DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. - This looks like a client side error.

Comment: yeah.. i think the error came from datatable plugin. btw thanks for submiting the answer. your model and controller work, but the view from another answer work too..